# TabLayout Icon using view Pager

Tags: java

```
package com.example.haider_khan.simple_tablayout;

import android.support.design.widget.TabLayout;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentStatePagerAdapter;
import android.support.v4.view.ViewPager;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    Toolbar toolbar;
    TabLayout tab;
    ViewPager vp;
    MyPagerAdapter adapter;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        adapter = new MyPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());
        toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.custom_appbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
        tab = (TabLayout) findViewById(R.id.custom_TabLayout);
        tab.addTab(tab.newTab().setText("Tab-1"));
        tab.addTab(tab.newTab().setText("Tab-2"));

        tab.addTab(tab.newTab().setIcon(R.drawable.saveaccount));
        vp = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.custom_viewPager);
        vp.setAdapter(adapter);
        tab.setupWithViewPager(vp);
        vp.addOnPageChangeListener(new TabLayout.TabLayoutOnPageChangeListener(tab));
    }
```

Problem: Unable to load image or text in tab when i use this tab.setupWithViewPager(vp); If i dont use this then it works fine but then tab is not connected to view pager.
I also tried getPagetitle a method from view pager it works fine but then i dont know how to use icon because it works for text only.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After bind viewPager to tabLayout can use this code:

```
tabLayout.setupWithViewPager(viewPager);
for (int i = 0; i < tabLayout.getTabCount(); i++) {
  tabLayout.getTabAt(i).setIcon(R.drawable.play);
}
```